# Concurrent API calls using Promise.allSettled with progress notification

Tags: reactjs, concurrency, promise, async-await

I have a React App from which I am making multiple concurrent API calls to the server. Each request takes about 15 to 20s to complete. I want to implement a progress notification bar to show the user how many numbers of requests are completed.

Say the API is to add users to DB. The typical code looks like this

```
var user1 = async () => await fetch('/adduser',data)
var user2 = async () => await fetch('/adduser',data)

dispatch(showloader());
Promise.allSettled([user1, user2, ...... ])
.then((r) => dispatch(hideLoader()));
```

I want some solution by which I can get the number of requests completed in runtime to update the progress bar which would look like below:

.............3/10 users added.............

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create common function to fetch user and pass different data to track

Note: this is just simple example not actual executable code

```
var completed =0;

const fetchuser = data=> {
fetch('/adduser',data).then(result => {
 completed++;
dispatch(showloader(".............$completed/10 users added............")) 
 });
}
var user1 = async () => await fetchuser('/adduser',data)
var user2 = async () => await fetchuser('/adduser',data)

Promise.allSettled([user1, user2, ...... ])
.then((r) => dispatch(hideLoader()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change a bit the logic. I will put an example below and explain over it a little...

```js
const addUser = userData =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch("/adduser", userData)
      .then(result => {
        //dispatch complete for an promise identifier
        dispatch(completed(userData.someProp));
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        dispatch(completed(userData.someProp));
        reject(e);
      });
  });

const users = [{ name: "abc", someProp: 1 }, { name: "bcd", someProp: 2 }];

//store an array with each user identifier
dispatch(start(users.map(user => user.someProp)));

Promise.allSettled(users.map(addUser)).then(r => {
  // do something with the result
  dispatch(finished(r));
});
```

I assumed you have an array of users to start with...

First you `dispatch` a start action with identifiers for each promise, in the above example that is `someProp`.

In the callback of the fetch function you `dispatch` another action with the identifier to remove it from the object stored initially.

This way you will always have an array with the status of the promises in the store, you could always count the `array`  to see how many there are left.

LE: You will need a `reducer` than handles all your actions